What are ways to invest in real estate other than buying property
I would like to know what are other ways to invest in real estate apart from actually buying a real estate and sitting on it. The latter comes with a significant hassle of being a homeowner and possibly dealing with tenants etc. which I prefer to avoid. But would like to invest in residential real estate as an asset class for the next 30y or so.

In what country?

@jcaron I was looking at the US but happy to consider other regions

The easiest way to passively invest in real estate is through funds (ETFs or mutual funds) that own Real Estate Investment Trusts (REITs). Investing in REITs directly is usually not possible for small passive investors, so investment firms set up funds that own multiple REITs.  This gets you exposure to real estate values and incomes without actually owning any real estate. You can pick funds that focus on either commercial or residential real estate to fit your goals.
I would note that the return on real estate funds is not significantly higher than stock market funds on average, and they are just as volatile - but it can diversify your portfolio and reduce volatility overall.
Another way is to buy a single property (I assume with a loan) and hire a property manager to deal with the issues you mention. The downside is that the loan and property manager eat into your return and often make it where your net cashflow is very small and you're only "profiting" on the change in value, which can't be materialized until you sell the house (or borrowing from it, costing you more interest). You still have the risk of the property going unrented for a long period, during which time you still need to pay the loan and the property manager, so the risk is much higher and often not worth the return.
You are correct that in general buying rental property is not passive at all - it is basically a part-time job. You need to decide if the income from that job is worth the effort compared to other opportunities.  Most "profit" from these properties is not in the rent collected but in buying them at a discount.

Standard reminder: efts, or traditional mutual funds. I still don't fully grok why some people prefer the former.

@keshlam good point - I've updated. I'm biased because I like to see intraday performance which you don't get from mutual funds.

There are also publicly traded homebuilders that offer exposure to the residential real estate market from the new build side.

These are construction builders that develop real estate? Could you give me an example to google?

Correct, the cash flow from rent isn't worth the investment when subtract property taxes and HOAs if any. However, the goal is to ride price appreciation and  target specific areas of the country etc. Is there an investment instrument that gives me exposure to the prices with smallest expenses?

@DStanley and what are the ways to invest actively then?

Buying property would be the active method. Whether you do that individually or through an investment group you create, it would still be active.

@Medan The construction builders are public companies that either buy real estate, build on it, and sell it, or build on a property already owned by someone else. They would not give you exposure to rising property prices, but on the margin charged by homebuilders.

"Is there an investment instrument that gives me exposure to the prices with smallest expenses?" Not that I am aware of - most real estate income is through rents, not through price appreciation.

As D Stanley's answer points out, you can invest in a REIT.  You can also invest in the real estate sector as a whole.  See here for information on sectors in general.  Examples of ETFs that represent the real estate sector are FREL and DFAR.  You can use those in your favorite stock tool and see competitors.  Here's Fidelity's page on FREL, and under Comparisons you'll see similar offerings from Vanguard, Schwab, etc.

I don't think this is what will meet my needs. For example in the USA the real estate market has significantly risen in the past 5 years in all areas. In some it is doubled while that isn't how this ETF performed. I am looking for some type of investments that tracks the prices in the country/region etc.

@Medan  Far be it from me to attempt to predict the future of real estate in the United States, but you have to ask yourself, if it's risen significantly in the last five years, what's it going to do for the next five?  If it seems too good to be true, it probably is. There are people who study the real estate market as their job, 40-60 hours a week. That's who you're competing against.  There's no such thing as a perfect investment. The better the return, the more the risk.  https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/052015/which-has-performed-better-historically-stock-market-or-real-estate.asp

not trying to predict anything here. Just trying to find a financial instrument that would follow real estate prices regardless of the direction. Basically replace a physical ownership with financial exposure. And I have something like case shiller to trace against.
